# MassAssignmentException in model .php

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am getting Error "MassAssignmentException in Model.php line 448: nom" When I am using create method, here is my code below:

```
class User extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'users';

    protected $fillable = ['nom','prenom','username','password','email','phone'];
}
```

AuthetificationController.php **(Controller)**

```
$parameters = $request->all();

$user = User::create($parameters);
```

I also did this:

```
$user = User::create([
    'nom'     => $request->input('nom'),
    'prenom'  => $request->input('prenom'),
    'username'=> $request->input('username'),
    'password'=> $request->input('password'),
    'email'   => $request->input('email'),
    'phone'   => $request->input('phone'),
]);
```

Still the same error

and when I do:

```
var_dump($parameters);
```

I get the following [results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZIau3.jpg)

Comment: be careful when you allow the mass assignment of critical fields like password or role. It could lead to a security issue because users could be able to update this fields values when you don't want to.

Comment: Did you create your own user model?

Comment: it's just for testing purposes , now im stuck i cant even save a new user

Comment: @NabinKunwar yes i did

Comment: then there are two user model? See which one is used on your controller. That will solve it.

Comment: i don't think so , because i deleted the model that generates automatically, i just rechecked there is only the one i created

Comment: can you post your all code of user model ??

Comment: @NabinKunwar you're awesome thanks , it's working , i dont know how there was a user model in vendor folder

Comment: @Drudge how can i solve the security issue with the password  ?

Comment: protected $hidden = [
        'password'
    ];

Comment: Great. happens sometime. For a sec I was wondering what could be the other issue. :D

Comment: then i take it off the $fillable ?

Comment: You might want to also run the password through Laravels hashing so the user can login

Answer (score 0):

try using in your controller

```
User::create(Request::all());
```